# Отрисовака букв посередине квадратов canvas

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

Имеется такой код:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Canvas from scratch</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script>
      function getRandomInt() {
              return Math.floor(Math.random() * (255 - 0)) + 0;
            }
         $(document).ready(function() {
                var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
                var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var coordinates = 70*i;
                    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb("+getRandomInt()+", "+getRandomInt()+", "+getRandomInt()+")";  
                    ctx.fillRect(coordinates, 0, 70, 70);  
     ctx.font = "bold 30px Verdana,sans-serif";
     ctx.lineWidth = 1;
     ctx.strokeText("Н", 25*i, 50);
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="700" height="70">
            <!-- Insert fallback content here -->
        </canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

Если его запустить то вырисовываются квадраты 10 шт. с разными цветами 70 на 70 px и буквы 10 шт. но как сделать чтобы каждая буква была по середине своего квадрата?

Comment: Ну так `ctx.strokeText("Н", 70*i + 25, 50);`  где 70 - ширина квадрата, 25 -отступ слева

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, `+25` - бррррррррррррр...

Comment: @Qwertiy согласен. мне было влом писать вычисляемое значение.. ибо там еще ширину текста можно задавать.... так что с учетом магических цифр ТС - это сработает)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, см. ответ. Канвас сам центрировать умеет.

Comment: @Qwertiy угу ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ctx.textAlign = 'center';
ctx.strokeText("Н", 70*(i+.5), 50);
```

```js
$(function() {
  function getRandomInt() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  }

  var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var coordinates = 70*i;
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb("+getRandomInt()+", "+getRandomInt()+", "+getRandomInt()+")";  
    ctx.fillRect(coordinates, 0, 70, 70);  
    ctx.font = "bold 30px Verdana,sans-serif";
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx.strokeText("Н", 70*(i+.5), 50);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="700" height="70"></canvas>
```